# Why I get Promise{<pending>}? Could someone explain me

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

```
const API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx';

const getData = fetch(`https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions?apiKey=${ API_KEY }`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => data)

console.log(getData);
```

Comment: Use `.then(console.log)` instead. `.then()` always returns a promise.

Comment: because that's what fetch returns, a Promise

Comment: @DBS: the api key is still available in the edit history. It's been leaked and needs to be invalidated, point.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, but I think obscuring it is better than nothing in the mean-time.